# How to phrase "analysis into a company"

Tags: american-english, british-english, academia

I want to say :

> Analysis **conducted at a** insurance company showed that...
>   or
>   Analysis **into a** insurance company showed that...

What is the best way to phrase this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would make it slightly less passive:

*"An analysis performed by the insurance company ..."*

or other material to indicate *who* performed the analysis and *where* it was performed as well as the issue being analyzed.  If you or your associates performed the analysis, you might phrase it:

*"An analysis performed by the authors into insurance company policies...'*

Comment: I would have worded it the same way.

Comment: Although I may would have started with "An" or "A"...

Comment: @Xarcell - updated the post as per your good suggestion.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent How to say "Our analysis at the insurance company..." third person research writing way?

Comment: @chamzzey that would work good as well. It rolls off if the tongue more easily...

Comment: @Xarcell I want remove "Our" word from that phrase. How will I be able to construct the same phrase "Our analysis at the insurance company..." without using "Our" OR "The analysis we did at the insurance company" without using word "we"

Comment: @chamzzey just as the same it is given by Gary. "An analysis performed by the insurance company". Sounds more professional.

Comment: @Xarcell Gary's answer interprets that the "insurance company performed the analyis.." but I want to say that "We performed the analysis into the insurance company.."

Comment: @Xarcell Writing more formally, you would refer to yourself as *the authors*............see my update.

Answer (score -4):

Use:

> The analysis that the company made says that ___.

Comment: This is wrong. It puts the sentence in the wrong perspective.